# Can $cos(u)$ be a moment generating function?

Tags: moment-generating-functions

I was asked in the probability course:

> Can a moment generating function of a random variable $Y$ be $\cos(u), -\infty <u<\infty$?

I proved that the first property of moment generating functions is satisfied, as in:

> $1=M_Y(0) = \cos(0) = 1$

But I couldn't carry on logically. What is missing so I could prove that indeed it can be? (My intuition says it can)

Comment: Well, suppose it is. Then what is the expected value for $Y^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at $E[Y^2]$ (which you know has to be $\geqslant 0$).

Comment: Thank you. It is $-1$, therefore it can't be.